# Why is my Count on joined tables not correct?

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, left-join, sql-server-2014

I have the following tables:

**STUDYA *(Alias J)***

```
LOGINID   RCD_NUM         DATE         TYPE
 8745       0         04/15/2018      PRELIM
 6548       0         08/19/2017      PRELIM
 7445       0         10/02/2017      PRELIM
 2867       0         03/19/2018      PRELIM
```

**TRIALS *(Alias G)***

```
LOGINID   RCD_NUM         DATE         TYPE
 8745       0          02/15/2017     ROLLUP
 7445       0          07/09/2016     ROLLUP
 2867       0          05/17/2017     ROLLUP
 2867       0          05/28/2017     ROLLUP
 5249       0          06/20/2017     ROLLUP
 1335       0          09/29/2017     ROLLUP
 9238       0          12/03/2017     ROLLUP
```

**SPRINT *(Alias H)***

```
 LOGINID   RCD_NUM         DATE        TYPE
  5521       0          01/10/2018     SPRNT
  8745       1          04/04/2018     SPRNT
  3487       0          11/14/2017     SPRNT
  6627       0          05/05/2018     SPRNT
```

And another table called **LOGIN** that I am matching the LOGINID's on.

I have the following query running on SQL Server 2014:

```
SELECT 'COUNTS', COUNT(G.LOGINID), COUNT(H.LOGINID), COUNT(J.LOGINID)
 FROM LOGIN F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  TRIALS G ON  F.LOGINID= G.LOGINID AND G.RCD_NUM = 
 F.RCD_NUM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  SPRINT H ON  F.LOGINID= H.LOGINID AND H.RCD_NUM = 
 F.RCD_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN  STUDYA J ON  F.LOGINID= J.LOGINID AND J.RCD_NUM = 
 F.RCD_NUM  

WHERE ( ( F.EFFDT = 
(SELECT MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB F_ED 
WHERE F.LOGINID = F_ED.LOGINID 
  AND F.RCD_NUM = F_ED.RCD_NUM 
  AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
AND F.EFFSEQ = 
(SELECT MAX(F_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB F_ES 
 WHERE F.LOGINID = F_ES.LOGINID 
  AND F.RCD_NUM = F_ES.RCD_NUM 
  AND F.EFFDT = F_ES.EFFDT) )
```

Here is the result of the above query:

```
(No column name)   (No column name)   (No column name)   (No column name) 
  COUNTS                  9                  5                  5
```

You can see the last column (COUNT(J.LOGINID)) is displaying **5** records, when in the actual table (above query) there is in fact only **4** records. I think it is because LOGINID 2867 has 2 rows in the TRIALS table, and 1 in STUDYA.

I've researched this and the recommendation seems to be doing the aggregation before the Joins. I'm struggling as to the best way of doing this though. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I strongly recommend that you ***do not*** use `g`, `h`, `j` as table aliases.  You are obfuscating your code.  The table names are not long, `TRIALS.LOGINID` is only 5 characters longer than `G.LOGINID` but ***significantly*** easy to debug, maintain, etc.

Comment: Your example data also doesn't match your example output.  You have 7 rows in `TRIALS` but your example output shows 9?

Comment: I tired your solution, however I am getting an Error message: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your data and use-case, you may get performance benefit from the approach you referred to: aggregate then join...

```
SELECT
 'COUNTS',
 COUNT(G.LOGINID) distinct_g, SUM(G.ROW_COUNT) row_count_g,
 COUNT(H.LOGINID) distinct_h, SUM(H.ROW_COUNT) row_count_h,
 COUNT(J.LOGINID) distinct_j, SUM(J.ROW_COUNT) row_count_j
FROM
 LOGIN F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
 SELECT LOGINID, RCD_NUM, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM TRIALS GROUP BY LOGINID, RCD_NUM
)
 G
  ON  F.LOGINID = G.LOGINID
  AND F.RCD_NUM = G.RCD_NUM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
 SELECT LOGINID, RCD_NUM, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM SPRINT GROUP BY LOGINID, RCD_NUM
)
 H
  ON  F.LOGINID = H.LOGINID
  AND F.RCD_NUM = H.RCD_NUM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
 SELECT LOGINID, RCD_NUM, COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM STUDYA GROUP BY LOGINID, RCD_NUM
)
 J
  ON  F.LOGINID = J.LOGINID
  AND F.RCD_NUM = J.RCD_NUM 

WHERE ( ( F.EFFDT = 
(SELECT MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB F_ED 
WHERE F.LOGINID = F_ED.LOGINID 
  AND F.RCD_NUM = F_ED.RCD_NUM 
  AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
AND F.EFFSEQ = 
(SELECT MAX(F_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB F_ES 
 WHERE F.LOGINID = F_ES.LOGINID 
  AND F.RCD_NUM = F_ES.RCD_NUM 
  AND F.EFFDT = F_ES.EFFDT) )
```

The optimiser can use predicate-push-down / macro-like-expansion to ensure the aggregation is only done for relevant rows and preserve use of indexes.

This pattern also allows you to get other statistics, such as the min/max date for each login/rcd combination.

***EDIT:***

Another pattern could include...

```
SELECT
 'COUNTS',
 SUM(G.ROW_COUNT) row_count_g,
 SUM(H.ROW_COUNT) row_count_h,
 SUM(J.ROW_COUNT) row_count_j
FROM
 LOGIN F 
OUTER APPLY
(
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM TRIALS WHERE LOGINID = F.LOGINID AND RCD_NUM = F.RCD_NUM
)
  G
OUTER APPLY
(
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM SPRINT WHERE LOGINID = F.LOGINID AND RCD_NUM = F.RCD_NUM
)
  H
OUTER APPLY
(
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM STUDYA WHERE LOGINID = F.LOGINID AND RCD_NUM = F.RCD_NUM
)
  J

WHERE ( ( F.EFFDT = 
(SELECT MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB F_ED 
WHERE F.LOGINID = F_ED.LOGINID 
  AND F.RCD_NUM = F_ED.RCD_NUM 
  AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
AND F.EFFSEQ = 
(SELECT MAX(F_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB F_ES 
 WHERE F.LOGINID = F_ES.LOGINID 
  AND F.RCD_NUM = F_ES.RCD_NUM 
  AND F.EFFDT = F_ES.EFFDT) )
```

Comment: This seems to work great! So essentially (correct me if I'm wrong) what this is doing is summing the total row counts in each table, before getting joined to other tables? Is ROW_COUNT a sql function? Thanks very much.

Comment: `AS ROW_COUNT` just gives that column the name `ROW_COUNT`.  You could use `AS lego` and then use `SUM(G.lego)`.  The sub-queries ensure that only one rows is returned per `LOGINID, RCD_NUM`, so that when the results are joined no duplication occurs.  One of the fields returned by the sub-query is how many source rows were aggregated together to for the output row *(using `COUNT(*)`)*.  Then you can just sum those values up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get distinct counts

```
 SELECT 'COUNTS', COUNT(distinct G.LOGINID), COUNT(distinct 
 H.LOGINID), COUNT(distinct J.LOGINID) ..
```